# What does the following lambda function in Haskell actually return?

Tags: haskell, lambda

Consider the following lambda function in Haskell:

```
(\x g n -> g (x * n))
```

It takes two parameters: a `Num` named `x` and a function `g` which takes a `Num` named `n` and returns something else. The lambda function returns another function of the same type as `g`:

```
(\x g n -> g (x * n)) :: Num a => a -> (a -> t) -> a -> t
```

What I don't understand is what does the expression `g (x * n)` actually represent. For example consider the following use case:

```
((\x g n -> g (x * n)) 2 id)
```

In this case `x` is `2` and `g` is `id`. However what is `n`? What does `g (x * n)` represent? By simple substitution it can be reduced to `id (2 * n)`. Is this the same as `id . (2 *)`? If so then why not simply write `(\x g -> g . (x *))`?

Comment: The function takes *three* parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to contradict chirlu.  `(\x g n -> g (x * n))` is a function of one argument.

Because all functions only take one argument. It's just that that function returns another function, which returns another function.

Desugared, it's the same as

```
\x -> \g -> \n -> g (x * n)
```

Which is pretty close to its type

```
Num a => a -> (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

Expanding your use case:

```
(\x g n -> g (x * n)) 2 id
```

Let's expand that

```
(\x -> \g -> \n -> g (x * n)) 2 id
```

Which is the same as

```
((\x -> \g -> \n -> g (x * n)) 2) id
```

Now we can apply the inner function to its argument to get

```
(let x = 2 in \g -> \n -> g (x * n)) id
```

or

```
(\g -> \n -> g (2 * n)) id
```

Now we can apply this function to its argument to get

```
let g = id in \n -> g (2 * n)
```

or

```
\n -> id (2 * n)
```

Which, via inspection, we can state is equivalent to

```
\n -> 2 * n
```

Or, point-free

```
(2*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close. The last example you gave, `((\x g n -> g (x * n)) 2 id)` represents a partial application of the function. It has a type signature of `Num a => a -> t` and is equivalent to the following: `\n -> id (2 * n)`.